# I didn't forget vs I haven't forgotten

Tags: word-usage, formality

Not a native English here and I'm having the issue with ***I didn't*** and ***I haven't*** use when saying

> *I hope I didn't forget/haven't forgotten anything*

(to say/mention when answering the email or message) at the end of the email/message/letter.

Can you please help me understand this in the easiest possible way.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, the two mean the same thing, but as noted [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337528/what-is-difference-between-i-did-not-and-i-have-not#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=Did%20%2D%20happened%20in%20the%20past,still%20have%20impact%20until%20now.), *did* should reference something that happened in the past, whereas *have* should reference something in the past that may still have impact or relevance today.

But if you're just worried about the case "I hope I didn't forget / haven't forgotten anything", they are both perfectly grammatically correct in the context, though "didn't forget" could be interpreted as *slightly* less formal, and more close to spoken language whereas "haven't forgotten" could be seen as more formal and more suited for written language.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That's actually what I was wondering, what is less or more formal and should I use one or the other in specific cases. TY!!

Comment: @Mia formality is often more social than grammatical, so it can be different depending on who you ask and where you are from, especially in cases like this where the difference is so small. If you truly wanted to sound professional, I might choose "haven't forgotten". It can also be seen as a little more friendly than "didn't forget". It's such a small difference that many native English speakers may not even pick up on it.